# Getting value error in train.test while eliminating features from dataset using RFE.what is the solution?

Tags: scikit-learn, dataset, iot, feature-extraction, sklearn-pandas

[valueError image part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lgw3q.png)
Here is the code for eliminating features where I am getting value errors. I want to use recursive feature elimination without specifying any features . I tried to use the RFE(Recursion feature elemination) model to automatically eliminate weak features with each iteration which I have unable to do.HERE is the link of the dataset. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1neYnunu6a_Mdn3NfRZsF8wE4gwMCpjAY/view?usp=sharing .I will be grateful if you suggest  me how to do it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from pandas import DataFrame
%matplotlib inline 

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive', force_remount=True) 

df.keys()
x=pd.DataFrame(df)
x.head()
X = df.drop(["Sub_Cat"],axis=1).values
y = df["Sub_Cat"].values
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,random_state=0)
X_train.shape,X_test.shape

sel=SelectFromModel(RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100,random_state=0,n_jobs=-1))
sel.fit(X_train,y_train)
sel.get_support()

[I am getting value error in this part][1]
```

Then i tried to do this also getting `X = df.drop(["Dst_IP","Timestamp","Flow_ID","Src_IP","Sub_Cat"],axis=1).values
y = df["Sub_Cat"].values
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,random_state=0)

```
X = df.drop(["Dst_IP","Timestamp","Flow_ID","Src_IP","Sub_Cat"],axis=1).values
y = df["Sub_Cat"].values
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,random_state=0)




sel=SelectFromModel(RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100,random_state=0,n_jobs=-1))
sel.fit(X_train,y_train)
sel.get_support()
```

I am still getting error:

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in ()
> 1 sel=SelectFromModel(RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100,random_state=0,n_jobs=-1))
> ----> 2 sel.fit(X_train,y_train)
> 3 sel.get_support()

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
81
82     """
---> 83     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
84
85

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Anomaly'

Comment: It seems you have strings in your Dataset, and Random Forest can't work with that, it need numerical values. You need to do a preprocessing step before training your model (encode/label or even drop if required).

Comment: How much I know label can't be dropped as it is one of the important feature.Can you tell me how to preprocessing?First time I am working on it.I will be grateful if you help how to solve it by giving the idea how to do it.I am working on recusrion feature elimination model.

Comment: Try using some of this techniques: `get_dummies()`, `OneHotEncoder`, `LabelEncoder`. The main purpose of this function is transform string categorical data to numerical one. Check with of this function fits better in you problem. Once your data is correctly preprocessed, you can start using the RFE model.